# OSM riverbank relations : unable to display them

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I am new in the GIS community and I am having trouble obtaining riverbanks in QGIS. It seems that when a relation is not complete, it is simply not displayed.

And since all riverbanks are now part of a huge relation and since all the nodes involved in this relation are NOT in my extract : QGIS is not displaying it!

Could someone help me? (currently, the only solution I have is to make a recursive request on averpass turbo .... but I can't get it from the planet-latest.osm.pbf file ..... )